# Android PJSIP openh264 usage issue

Tags: android, video, asterisk, pjsip, pjsua2

I'm working on voip video client application, witch is using PJSIP(PJSUA2) for client side and Elastics(ASTERISK) as a proxy-server.

I have already built the library according tutorial from pjsip.org and improved it into my project.

Registration\incoming calls handling\audio stream works fine.
But I have no video stream.

endpoint.videoCodecEnum() is empty;

Incoming call video count=0/index=-1;

There is an appropriate asterisk log:
Ignoring video stream offer because port number is zero

My build details:

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- android ndk downgraded to r13b
- android sdk tools downgraded to r22.0.5
- build target platform for openh264 and pjsua is android-24
- config_site.h:

  #define PJ_CONFIG_ANDROID 1

  #include < pj/config_site_sample.h >

  #define PJMEDIA_HAS_VIDEO 1

  #define PJMEDIA_HAS_OPENH264_CODEC 1
- pjsua2 built with openh264(... usability ... ok), using libyuv by default(as recommended by tutorial) for armeabi, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a and placed to appropriate folders
- structure:
  .../app/src/main/

  java/

  ```
    com/...

    org.pjsua2/...
  ```

  jniLibs/

  ```
    arm64-v8a/
        libopenh264.so
        libpjsua2.so
    armeabi/
        libopenh264.so
        libpjsua2.so
    armeabi-v7a
        libopenh264.so
        libpjsua2.so
  ```

  res/...

Does somebody faced with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my own inattention.

If you have faced with the same issue - check your config_site.h file location.

It should be:
'your pjproject path'/pjlib/include/pj/config_site.h

The file content should contain at least:

#define PJ_CONFIG_ANDROID 1

#define PJMEDIA_HAS_VIDEO 1

#include < pj/config_site_sample.h >

Comment: How can i build anroid pjsip app with more than one  cpu architecture support .. eg in your jnilibs it support arm64 ,armeabi as well as armeabi v7a. i have notice that i can build for only one architecture at a time.